# javascript syntax - rosetta code merge sort

Tags: javascript, syntax, semantics, mergesort

On the [rosettacode page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#JavaScript) for merge sort the javaScript example for has the following function:

```
1 function merge(left,right,arr){
2    var a=0;
3    while(left.length&&right.length)
4       arr[a++]=right[0]<left[0]?right.shift():left.shift();
5    while(left.length)arr[a++]=left.shift();
6    while(right.length)arr[a++]=right.shift();
7 }
```

Can someone please explain what is happening on line 4?

Comment: What exactly you don't understand there? Try to split into multiple lines / replace `?:` with if...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was not familar with that syntax. There is comparison `right[0]<left[0]` and then the **boolean** result of which `?` is evaluated true=`right.shift()` `:` false=`left.shift()`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. `?:` is commonly called "ternary operator" (formal name "conditional operator") - search and see details (the same behavior in many languages JS, C,C++,C#, Java,...)

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov, is it ternary because of the three values `(bool, condition1, condition2)`?

Comment: yes - similar to binary (+,-, *,...) and unary (unary "-" as in `(-1)`). See [Arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity).

Answer (score 0):

`arr` get sorted. if the first cell inside `left` bigger than the first cell inside `right` then (`?`) `right.shift()` - it means that the the first cell inside `right` is removed & returned (pushed to `arr`) otherwise (`:`), `left` get shifted.